# Passing a java variable to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following piece of code which is a input content for a js lib:

```
content:'<a href="x.com" onclick="confirmDel("<%=user.name%>")" > <img src="delete.png" alt="Delete" width="15px" height="15px"></a></div>'

confirmDel(name)
{
 if(confirm("delete " + name +" ?"))
   {
     // Do delete stuff
   } else
   {
   return false;
   }
}
```

when I click the delete link, it does not prompt me with the delete confirmation alert! what am I missing here? Is it about the way I pass the variable to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 content:'<a href="x.com" onclick="confirmDel(\''+<%=user.name%>+'\')" > <img src="delete.png" alt="Delete" width="15px" height="15px"></a></div>'
```

problem with passing parameter in the onclick..use escape character..

Comment: No this should work fine, its not broken, and actually will break if you do it this way.  It will try to treat the name as a variable rather than a string.

Comment: It would be better without scriptlets usage since is deprecated. Check [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

```
confirmDel(name)
{
 if(confirm("delete " + name +" ?"))
   {
     // Do delete stuff
   } else
   {
   return false;
   }
}
```

This is incorrect.  Its halfway between declaring a function and calling it, but doesn't really do either.

You need to declare the function and then call it to execute that code.  You're calling it in the onclick section now, but you need to define it correctly

```
function confirmDel(nameStr)
{
 if(confirm("delete " + nameStr +" ?"))
   {
     // Do delete stuff
   } else
   {
   return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: your function declaration still won't work as is though.  You need to add the function keyword in there somewhere.